# Migrating emails in Plesk

Tags: plesk

I am trying to move emails from an old plesk 11 server to a new plesk 12 server.

The server hosts multiple domains with their own subscriptions so I am transferring one at a time. Unfortunately one subscription on the old server holds multiple different domains and the associated email addresses. I want to transfer the email accounts from the old server in this bundled up subscription into a new subscription on the new server.

What is the best way to go about this?

ALSO
I am transferring the sites and then updating the DNS to point to the new server.

TLDR
Migrate emails from an old server's subscriptions into a new server's different subscription.

Comment: Have you found a solution

Comment: Thanks! but I found out, that just coping the files/folders on /var/qmail/mailnames/ is much more easier and faster (and plesk indipendent)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created all the subscriptions on the new server and then using the migration manager, when I migrated the sites email settings they were sorted into the relevent subscriptions.